# DeviceIoControl assistance

Tags: c++, winapi

Using C++, trying to use DeviceIOControl to send mouse clicks directly through driver. Very little documentation seems to exist on this. Very annoying. This is all I figured out so far. Have no idea what goes into any parameter after dwIoControlNode. I've seen keyboard examples, but no mouse ones.

EDIT: Appreciate your help Remy, will try your suggestions tomorrow, been working on this all day and am braindead.

```
int i = 0;
GUID MouseyBoi;
HANDLE HIDD = NULL;
HIDD_ATTRIBUTES DeviceAttributes;
ULONG Needed, l;
HDEVINFO DeviceInfoSet;
SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA DevData;
PSP_INTERFACE_DEVICE_DETAIL_DATA DevDetail;
PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA InfData;

DeviceInfoSet = SetupDiGetClassDevs(&GUID_DEVCLASS_MOUSE, NULL, NULL, DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE);
SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(DeviceInfoSet, &DevData, NULL, 0, &Needed, 0);
DevDetail = (SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA*)GlobalAlloc(GPTR, 1 + 4);
DevDetail->cbSize = sizeof(SP_INTERFACE_DEVICE_DETAIL_DATA);

HIDD = CreateFile(DevDetail->DevicePath, GENERIC_WRITE, NULL, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
HidD_GetAttributes(HIDD, &DeviceAttributes);
std::cout << DeviceAttributes.VersionNumber << std::endl;
std::cout << DeviceAttributes.ProductID;
```

Comment: I just read in a programming book that this may be futile?

"It isn’t possible to open a handle to a mouse or keyboard collection because the system input thread has
opened these devices exclusively. Furthermore, these devices don’t appear in the enumeration of the HID
interface GUID. (HIDCLASS doesn’t advertise the HID interface GUID for keyboard

Comment: and mice so as to
prevent some random user-mode program from opening those devices before the system’s own raw input
thread can do so.) It does you no good to register a private interface GUID for your device because
HIDCLASS will fail an IRP_MJ_CREATE directed to the main device object. Consequently, there is no
way to communicate with a custom mouse or keyboard driver using standard methods."

Comment: That info should have been posted as an [edit] to your question, not in comments

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need to escape `\` characters in a string literal, eg:

`LPCWSTR FileName = L"USB\\VID_046D&PID_C07E&MI_00\\6&361cde46&0&0000";`

And second, this is not a valid file/device path that you can open with `CreateFile()` anyway.  It should look more like this:

`LPCWSTR FileName = L"\\\\?\\USB#VID_046D&PID_C07E&MI_00#6&361cde46&0&0000#{<guid>}";`

You can use `SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail()` to get a device path that `CreateFile()` will accept.

That being said, once you do manage to open a handle to the USB device, the `DeviceIoControl()` call should look like the following, since you are just inserting input data, not getting any output back out (but I could be wrong, as there is no documentation for `IOCTL_MOUSE_INSERT_DATA` that I can find):

```cpp
MOUSE_INPUT_DATA MouseInput = {};
MouseInput.UnitId = 0;
MouseInput.ButtonFlags = MOUSE_LEFT_BUTTON_DOWN;
// set other fields as needed ...

DeviceIoControl(hFile, IOCTL_MOUSE_INSERT_DATA, &MouseInput, sizeof(MOUSE_INPUT_DATA), NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: Good to know I am not crazy and it is very hard to find documentation on this, which is why I resorted to reading WDM books from... 2003.

Comment: Another possible approach would be to build a WDM filter driver that would sit between one of the layers between the mouse usb hardware and the OS. Then using deviceiocontrol messages to your filter driver insert mouse movements and clicks into the data stream. Not a simple project though.

Comment: Ok, I edited original post. This is at least outputting something. How do I check if it selected the correct mouse device? I'm looking in device manager and I do not see any numbers matching the output. Both Vendor and Product ID, when cout'ed, display 52428.

Comment: @Culbrelai You are allocating `DevData` but not filling it in before using its `DevicePath`